# Change the name of an attribute in my DefaultDaoImpl

Tags: java, autocomplete

I have a DefaultDaoImpl which every Dao extends. This is the persist method signature:

```
public abstract class DefaultDaoImpl<T> implements DefaultDao<T>
    @Override
    public boolean persist(T entity){
        // my code
    }
}
```

When I extend it in my classes I do this:

```
public class UsuerDaoImpl extends DefaultDaoImpl<User>{
    // code
}
```

When I use my `UsuerDaoImpl` the auto complete uses `entity` name as a parameter.

I want to use `user` instead of `entity`, so when i call my `UsuerDaoImpl` I will have an auto-complete like this:

```
myUserDao.persist(user);
```

instead of:

```
myUserDao.persist(entity);
```

Anyone knows if it is possible?

Edit:

I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Eclipse? Try window / preferences / java / editor / content assist and check "Insert best guessed arguments".